# HP LaserJet 4250 Printer Networking Problems

Tags: static-ip, network-printer

We've been trying to assign a static IP address to an HP LaserJet 4250 Printer. When we click on the networking tab it asks for a username and password, however it says the admin user is Unauthorized.

We've tried IE 8, Firefox, and Chrome and have even updated the firmware to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks Chris for answering my question, however it never reset like it was suppose too. We solved the problem by setting the IP address directly on the printer, not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The password has been changed, or someone messed with the users, etc. You'll have to reset all the settings (unless you know the correct un/pw): Turn the switch on the side off, hold the green GO button, turn the power switch on, wait until it is completely booted up, release the GO button.